# populating data from db and displaying in text box from a text box without submitting the form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

please check the below code iam not getting output

I wanted to query database by typing in a text field and all the matching data related to the text field should be populated on the other empty fields by means of Ajax without submitting the form on the same page so i tried this code but it doesn't work.

The tutorial i saw was working perfectly i don't know what wrong i did as iam not getting the result....please check the below link for tutorial there u can understand what i exactly need...

I implemented this by seeing this tutorial http://www.crackajax.net/popform.php

Iam a newbie please help me with this issue.......

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
var url = "index.php?param="; 
function getagentids() 
{ 
var idValue = document.getElementById("agid").value; 
var myRandom = parseInt(Math.random()*99999999); 
//cache buster http.open("GET", url + escape(idValue) + "&rand=" + myRandom, true); 
http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse; http.send(null);
}

function handleHttpResponse() 
{ 
if (http.readyState == 3) 
{ 
results = http.responseText.split(",");
document.getElementById('agtel').value = results[0]; 
document.getElementById('agfn').value = results[1]; 
document.getElementById('agid').value = results[2]; 
} 
} 
function getHTTPObject() {
var xmlhttp;
/*@cc_on
     @if (@_jscript_version >= 5)
      try {
          xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
          } catch (e) {
          try {
              xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
              } catch (E) {
              xmlhttp = false;
              }
          } 
     @else
      xmlhttp = false;
     @end @*/
    if (!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
     try {
       xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
       } catch (e) {
       xmlhttp = false;
       }
      }
      return xmlhttp;
    }


 var http = getHTTPObject(); // We create the HTTP Object
 </script>

 </head>
 <body>
 <form name="schform"> 
 <table> 
 <tr> 
 <td>Contact ID:</td> 
 <td><input id="agid" type="text" name="contactid" onKeyUp="getagentids();"></td> 
 </tr> 
<tr> 
<td>Person Name1:</td> 
<td><input id="agtel" type="text" name="contacttel"></td> 
</tr> 
<tr> 
<td>Person Name2:</td> 
<td><input id="agfn" type="text" name="contactfullname"></td> </tr> 

<td><input type="reset" value="Clear">
</td> 
<td></td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
</form>



<?php
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","spikadb");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

 if(strlen($param)>0)
 { 
 $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE flat_no LIKE '$param%'"); 
 if(mysql_num_rows($result)==1) { while($myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 { 
 $personname1 = $myrow["name"]; 
 $personname2 = $myrow["name2"]; 
 $flatno = $myrow["flat_no"];

 $textout .= $personname1.",".$personname2.",".$flatno;
 } 
    } 
    else 
    { 
    $textout=" , , ,".$param; 
    } 
        } 
        echo $textout;
 mysqli_close($con);
?> 




</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please put a little effort into formatting your code, and also try to include only the relevant code.

Comment: and do yourself a favor and start using parameterized queries!